# 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'Conv2DTranspose'

Tags: python

I have a problem with load layers Conv2DTranspose.

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D,MaxPooling2D,Activation, BatchNormalization, Conv2DTranspose
from keras.models import Sequential


#Instantiate an empty model
model = Sequential()

#Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, input_shape=(32,32,3), kernel_size=(2,2), strides=(1,1), padding='valid', name="conv1"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu',  name='bn1'))


#Decoder 
model.Conv2DTranspose(filters=4000, kernel_size=(2,2), strides=(1,1), padding='valid', name="conv6")
model.summary()
```

But, I get this:

```
AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'Conv2DTranspose'
```

I tried with library tensorflow but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing anything about `keras` I can see, that you try to initialize `model.Conv2DTranspose`, which is of type `Sequential.Conv2DTranspose` because `model` is of type `Sequential`. But due to the import statement `Conv2DTranspose` is not part of `Sequential`.

You probably have to create the `Conv2DTranspose` object on itself and somehow pass it to your `model` object.

Comment: As I said, I don't know `keras`, but probably by removing the leading `model.`.